# Objective C - iPhone: different DetailViewControllers for TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have followed the tutorial by Ray Wenderlich at http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

The In-App Purchase basically works but when I tap on different items in the list (of MasterViewController) the same DetailViewController is shown. I want to have different DetailViewControllers for different items in the list. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you open an existing `DetailViewController`? I tried to look through the tutorial briefly, but I missed this part.

Comment: When the user taps on an item, how will you determine which DetailViewController you want to show?

Comment: MasterViewController is connected to DetailViewController in the storyboard. But the MasterViewController in the storyboard only shows a prototype cell called @Cell in MasterViewController.m

Comment: Do you want to use different types of cells for the different types of items that presumably go to different DetailViewControllers?

Comment: No the prototype cell loads different items in the table from the app-store, but when clicking on one of them I have to show a page that is different from another page. Maybe using a nib, as is suggested in the tutorial, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: How do you determine which page you want to see based on the item you tap? Can you give a specific example? (for example: "When I tap on a type of car, I should see a car detail view, but when I tap on a type of boat, I should see a boat detail view"). And do the products you get from the app store contain the necessary metadata to make that determination?

Comment: I am not sure how the tutorial-code handles this, but the method + (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance returns one of the productIdentifiers like @"com.razeware.inapprage.drummerrage",
                                      @"com.razeware.inapprage.itunesconnectrage", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using storyboards and prototype cells, here's how I'd recommend doing this:

1. For each type of item, create a prototype cell with its own reuse identifier.
2. For each type of item, create a detail view controller specifically tailored to display that type of item.
3. For each type of item, create a new scene in the storyboard, set that scene's view controller to the detail view controller you created in step 2, and wire up the corresponding prototype cell to push its respective detail view controller.
4. In MasterDetailViewController, modify -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to return the appropriate cell for the product at indexPath (remember that in step 1, you created different prototype cells for each item type).
5. Implement -prepareForSegue to configure the destination view controller appropriately for its item.

Alternatively, you may want to consider whether you can use one DetailViewController for every item and configure it differently depending on the item being displayed.

Comment: How can I use 1 DetailViewController for each item? How to configure it differently?

Comment: That really depends on your specific needs. Without knowing more about what you want to show for each item, it's difficult to answer.

Comment: I now have multiple cells in a table, but when clicking on them the same DetailViewController is shown. I want to show different pages that have at least a button and do something on click. How do I configure the DetailViewController for each cell? Can you maybe give me a tutorial to follow?